# How can I send raw POST data with cURL? (PHP)

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm attempting to send raw POST data to a page using **$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA**, but my attempts failed and an undefined index notice was given.

I have attempted the following:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Raw POST data');   // Doesn't seem to work at all.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('Raw POST data'));   // 0 => Raw POST data
```

I did some research and some people had suggested sending a header (***Content-Type: text/plain***) in the request, which didn't seem to affect anything.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some odd reason the aforementioned header thing seems to fix it. Previously it wasn't working, and I'm unsure why it works now.

Anyway, for those who don't know, this is the code:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
```

Comment: I actually required a different Content-Type but this got me on the right track

Answer (score 4):

You get an error in the **response** part of your sender/receiver cycle.

While this might very well be a problem of the **sender** (which does not send a proper request), it may also be caused by a misconfiguration in the **receiving** PHP script. To wit, even if the request is correct, the receiver might nonetheless not have `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` available.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

> Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA containing the raw POST data.
>   Otherwise, the variable is populated only with unrecognized MIME type
>   of the data. However, the preferred method for accessing the raw POST
>   data is php://input. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

So the first thing to check is whether `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is indeed populated, which from the page above requires either:

1. the .ini variable `always_populate_raw_post_data` is True,
2. or the POST is sent with a `Content-Type` that the POST handler does not recognize (maybe one could use "text/raw")

At this point, the correct way of sending data would be

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode('Raw POST data'));
```

However, note that **the recommended way of receiving those data** would be not to rely on `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` at all, but to read the contents of the virtual file `php://input`.

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data.

Comment: I'm quite certain the receiver is fine as sending the POST data manually works fine (using the Live HTTP Headers add-on for Firefox).
I'm aware of php://input and how it's better, however, in this case I require a solution for $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Well, in that case you can set the always-populate-raw-post-data setting in the PHP.INI; or you can send an "unrecognized" (whatever *that* means) "MIME type" to force population of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Updating answer...

Comment: This answer seems unrelated to the original question, which was really about performing an HTTP request using libcurl from PHP and not about accessing POST data sent to a PHP script running in a web server.

Comment: @Shadocko - the original question **did** describe an undefined index error *while accessing POST data from the PHP script running in a web server*. I'll readily admit that in this specific case the error was in the sending script, but the solution I gave is related to a situation I observed first hand, and know to occur. While it is not an answer for this specific case, it may well be for someone else looking for the same thing.

Comment: @lserni OK, sorry for the downvote, didn't realise that the PHP script indeed received data in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` before bundling it in another HTTP request, so your answer can be useful. My vote is locked in but I will cancel it if you edit your answer.

Comment: That's okay, no problem. Actually, I *have* been unclear; on re-reading, your misunderstanding was in large part my own fault, and editing the answer is beneficial. Thanks for calling my attention to that; let me know if the answer is clearer now.

Comment: @lserni - your answer is actually so much clearer now that I upvoted it, even if it's not the one I was looking for when I stumbled here.

Comment: Wow, thanks! But what was it that you were looking for? I'd like to help :-)

Comment: @lserni - My problem was posting huge files as raw POST body. I eventually solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508850/how-to-raw-post-huge-xml-file-with-curl-php/31696809#31696809