# Translating "data-binary" from cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl, ibm-watson

I need to recreate this in PHP:

```
curl -X POST --user <username>:<password>
--header "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
--header "Accept: application/json"
--data-binary @<filename>
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile"
```

I've got this:

```
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Language: en';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en';

$simple_data = 'washingtonpost by the intelligence community';
    curl_setopt_array( $ch2, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $simple_data,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => $request_headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'XXXX:YYYY',
    )
    );
    $response2 = curl_exec( $ch2 );
```

What my code doesn't account for is the `--data-binary` part, but I'm not sure how to "translate" this into PHP. In addition, can I use data binary with plain text (the API accepts it) instead of JSON?

Comment: In your code, `CURLOPT_HEADER` should be `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set request headers.  Otherwise, POSTFIELDS is correct as is with the custom Content-Type.

Comment: @drew010 This was exactly the problem! Thank you! If you submit as an answer, I can accept. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is already a `--data-binary` equivalent. See the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` API docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it. libcurl will not convert or encode it for you in any way.

Compare that to the [docs for the command-line `--data-binary` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary):

> This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.

As far as the second part of your question:

> can I use data binary with plain text (the API accepts it) instead of JSON

Yeah, both for `--data-binary` from the command line and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` from the API.

Comment: Thanks...this is giving me `415 Unsupported Media Type` errors that I can't track down given the very simple string I'm trying to send in this example.

Comment: I would think that `415 Unsupported Media Type` is just the service looking at the `Content-Type: text/plain` header and saying it doesn’t support that (though why I dunno since your question indicates it should). I guess changing that to `application/json` and trying again would be the thing to do (if you’ve not already). But anyway as far as I can see, that 415 isn’t being caused by any malformedness in what your libcurl code is sending.

Comment: I'm running the exact same thing using the CLI and it works perfectly fine. Is there something that's being changed (or not changed) in the translation that I'm missing?

Comment: I think the problem is just what’s mentioned by in the comment above at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358104/translating-data-binary-from-curl-to-php/42358362?noredirect=1#comment71868188_42358104 That is, you need `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a way to stream the upload without `multipart/form-data`, the key is to cheat curl, first we tell him to PUT, then to POST:

```
    <?php
    
    $file_local_full = '/tmp/foobar.png';
    $content_type = mime_content_type($file_local_full);

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: $content_type", // or whatever you want
    );

    $filesize = filesize($file_local_full);
    $stream = fopen($file_local_full, 'r');

    $curl_opts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_PUT => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $stream,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_opts);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    fclose($stream);

    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
        throw new \Exception($error_msg);
    }

    curl_close($curl);
```

credits: [How to POST a large amount of data within PHP curl without memory overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627346/how-to-post-a-large-amount-of-data-within-php-curl-without-memory-overhead)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as an array (which if you use `CURLFile` it **will** be), the post will be formatted as multipart, breaking the `data-binary` part.

I did not find a way to use CURLFile wihtout the `multipart/form-data` side effect...

What I use is this, but it uses `file_get_contents` which is not very memory friendly (it will load the entire file in memory):

```
    <?php

    $file_local_full = '/tmp/foobar.png';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", // or whatever you want
    );

    // if the file is too big, it should be streamed
    $curl_opts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents($file_local_full),
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1
    );
    // echo "curl_opts:\n" . print_r($curl_opts, true) . "\n"; exit;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_opts);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```