# PHP Post value is empty

Tags: php, curl

I am encoding a PDF as base64 and sending a post request via `cURL`. When I encode a big PDF the post field in `cURL` becomes empty. Which configuration in `php.ini` I need to tweak in order send huge post payload via cURL?

Comment: can you use `$data = file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of `$data = $_POST`. I think $_POST only takes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data type (I am not sure. it's worth a try)

Comment: Thats what I did...still empty. but if I encode a smaller PDF its OK.

Comment: in php.ini you will find two lines; can you change the values for `upload_max_filesize` and
`post_max_size`

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 2000M, post_max_size = 0 (disabled)..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Peshraw H. Ahmed on his second comment,`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` is the parameter that would do the work. But if you're file is really big (say 20 Mb) and your php is allowed to use maximum 16MB, then it might fail too. So in that case, also check `memory_limit` parameter and set it higher.

However, as you're trying to send file using Curl, also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627346/how-to-post-a-large-amount-of-data-within-php-curl-without-memory-overhead) to use curl infile option.